# React radio input only changes when label is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a controlled component for a radio input.
the radio button doesn't get checked unless I click on the label.

The actual backend state value changes and the logic I'm using for the 'checked' attribute is firing, it just doesn't want to render properly.

(In this example I'm using a custom field object I created for my purposes.)

```
function RadioInput (props) {

    return (
        <input
            type='radio'
            name={props.field.name}
            disabled={props.field.disabled}
            onChange={ (evt) => {console.log('fire onChange'); props.field.onChange(props.choice) } }
            onFocus={ (evt) => props.field.onFocus(evt) }
            onBlur={ (evt) => props.field.onBlur(evt) }
            style={errStyle}

            id={props.field.name + '-' + props.choice}
            value={props.choice}
            checked={(console.log('fire checked', props.field.name, props.choice, props.field.value, props.choice === props.field.value)) || (props.choice === props.field.value) }
        />
    )
}
```

So when I click on the actual radio button, I can see the log output firing from checked and all the values are correct. it just doesn't want to render properly.

the same console output is generated when I click on a label for this input but that renders the radio checked state properly.

What am I doing wrong?

**update:**
no function for label. just using straight label with htmlFor

```
<label htmlFor={"radio button name"}>LABEL TEXT</>
```

**update2:**
here is a codepen that demonstrates this works. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pegxyr?editors=0010

I'll be re-reviewing my code to figure this out

**update3:**
I gave up and just made a custom css radio button. this is much less than ideal because I can't tab through a form as one would normally expect. super frustrating.

Comment: the value of checked property should be set as true. Can you try setting,
checked = {props.field.val===true} something like this and then making props.field.value as true ?

Comment: Can you show your function that you are using for label?

Comment: @nitesh: the checked property will be either true or false. the value here must be correct otherwise clicking on the label wouldn't work either.

Comment: @deividas: no function for label, just using the default label element and htmlFor attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason this should not work. The problem might be with your `onChange` function, which would not change or with the values that you are passing to your `Input` component.

I have created a working example for you: http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/bqEmGp

Maybe by matching what I've done you can update your component successfully.

Comment: Thank you for putting that pen together. I modified it slightly to resemble more what i'm doing. As you mention, there is no reason why this doesn't work so it must be something local on my side. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pegxyr?editors=0010

Comment: @w-- so do you still need help or is it resolved? If you still need help it would be nice if you can add a modified pen to your OP so I can have a look at it.

Comment: I'm going to re-review what i've got. I hit enter before pasting my modified pen just now. i edited the comment. i'll also put it in the OP